# Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column '' cannot be null, But the column value is not null

Tags: mysql

This is my query

```
UPDATE `tblaccount` 
SET `updatedon` = ?, 
    `updatedby` = ?,
    `talentpoolfields` = ?   
WHERE `id` = 5
```

Here Talentpoolfields value is being assigned, but it is giving the error.

Whole Query :

```
UPDATE `tblaccount` 
SET `updatedon` = 1663214423, 
    `updatedby` = 28258,
    `talentpoolfields` = '{"id": {"allow_on_talent_pool":false}, 
        "sourceid": {"allow_on_talent_pool":false}, 
        "srno":{"allow_on_talent_pool":false}, 
        "candidatename":{"allow_on_talent_pool":false}}' 
WHERE `id` = 5
```

Comment: *Whole Query* Where this SQL text is taken from? you extract it from General Log? Provide complete DDL (the output for `SHOW CREATE TABLE tblaccount;`). Check for triggers presence.

Comment: Are there columns other than those 4?